# WooCommerce child theme vs completely custom theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes

I'm trying to decide whether to use a child theme on a commercially available theme or bite the bullet and build a completely custom theme?

I'm relatively new to coding so it would be my first theme build.
Any resources or tutorials for building a WooCommerce theme would be gratefully received.
I already have quite a large site and commercial themes seem to have a lot of junk attached to them. It's not going to be an overly complicated theme so just trying to weigh up my options. Any advice? thanks

Comment: If you're building an e-commerce website for a client and you have a deadline, go for a child theme. If this is a personal project and/or you don't have a deadline, then learning how to build a theme from scratch could be a good idea if you want to learn more in depth how WordPress works.

Comment: This is a personal project so have plenty of time to work on it. Does anyone have any good resources and tutorials to get me started?

Comment: Starter theme and resources: https://roots.io/ For WC, please refer to: https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/theming/